# supress verbose and show only curl output command

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I am using curl command like following `curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' some_url -d '{ "some":"json"}'` and getting output like below.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 14:28:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3925
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.23
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000

{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [{
        "hostid": "10225",
        "proxy_hostid": "0",
        "host": "sgw-2585-bus",
        "status": "0"
    }]
}
```

I just want the json output of curl command for further processing. how can i achieve it.

Note: curl doesn't show json output like this i've formatted json block.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the -s or --silent option?

[curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to omit the `-i` flag

From the curl man page:

```
   -i, --include
          Include the HTTP-header in the output. The HTTP-header includes things like server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and more...

          See also -v, --verbose.
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the -i switch from your command. This code below gives your pure JSON response

```
curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' some_url -d '{ "some":"json"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your don't have a .curlrc file with -v (or other unwanted flags) in it.

I had same issue as OP, always getting verbose output without my asking for it, and turned out there was a .curlrc file with some undesirable stuff in it.